# Install crystal report on visual studio 2010 express 32bit

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have project and I need to open it .. visual studio can't read rpt file

I installed crystal report run time 32bit but the same problem
Please how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your existing crystal report at your current working project. You can show it using:
[image]